# Handling Array values in PHP MYSQL POST method

Tags: php, arrays, forms, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this. This array value will be a dynamic value. So there will be array starting from author0 to authorN (where N represents any numbers).
The order will be in the below sequential only.

```
    Array
    (
        [author0] => 31
        [percent0] => 10
        [start0] => 2014-05-20
        [end0] => 2014-05-21
        [author1] => 70
        [percent1] => 20
        [start1] => 2014-05-21
        [end1] => 2014-05-21
        [author2] => 75
        [percent2] => 20
        [start2] => 2014-05-21
        [end2] => 2014-05-21
    )
```

I need to store the above array values in db as follows

table name: author_percentage

```
    author          percentage      start           end
    31              10              2014-05-20      2014-05-21
    70              20              2014-05-21      2014-05-21
    75              20              2014-05-21      2014-05-21
```

So how can I achieve that?

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an temp array:)

```
$tempArr = array();
foreach($array as $rows) {
     $tempArr[] = $rows;
     if(count($tempArr) == 4) {
       $query = "INSERT INTO author_percentage ('author','precentage','start','end') VALUES ($tempArr[0],$tempArr[1],$tempArr[2],$tempArr[3])";
       $tempArr = array();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
$i = 0;
while(array_key_exists("author". $i, $array))
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO author_percentage (author, percentage, start, end) VALUES ('" .         $array['author'.$i] . "', '" . $array['percentage'.$i] . "', '" . $array['start'.$i] . "', '"   . $array['end'.$i] . "')";
  //execute SQL here, like$mysqli::query($sql);
  $i++;
}
```

assuming that your array is saved within the variable $array.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simpler way to do what you want. It is much elegant to group each index category to individual arrays.
    //PARENT ARRAY TO STORE CHILDREN
    $data = array();

```
//ITERATE YOUR DATA INTO INDIVIDUAL ARRAYS INSIDE PARENT $data ARRAY
while($datasource != 0){
    $data[] = array(
        author  => 31
        percent => 10
        start   => 2014-05-20
        end     => 2014-05-21
);
```

Now you will have a pretty array tree that you can quickly manipulate using foreach
    $data[0] = array(
        author  => 31
        percent => 10
        start   => 2014-05-20
        end     => 2014-05-21
    );

```
$data[1] = array(
    author  => 31
    percent => 10
    start   => 2014-05-20
    end     => 2014-05-21
);

... and so on
```

Happy coding my friend.

[hack some PHP from my blog](http://nelson.arena.co.ke)